# JavaMelody throws WebBeansDeploymentException

Tags: java, apache, tomcat8, health-monitoring, java-melody

Good evening,

I want to monitor my webapplication and read about the ease of javamelody. From the documentation it should be as easy as copying javamelody and jrobin into the webapp's WEB-INF/lib and restart the tomcat.

But I get a WebBeansDeploymentException when I startup tomcat with these two jar's in my WEB-INF/lib: javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar, jrobin-1.5.9.jar

I'm using openJPA, my beans.xml file is empty, but does exist.

My configuration:

```
Apache Tomcat: 8.5
Java: 1.8
javaee-api: 7.0
javamelody-core: 1.71.3
jrobin: 1.5.9
```

Since I did not find much about this issue on stackoverflow or google, I'd be thankful for any hint or link for further reading!

Thanks in advance!

Full Stacktrace:

> Jul 06, 2018 10:45:27 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle
>   startApplication SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
>   org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: WebBeans
>   configuration defined in
>   jar:file:/home/xxxxxxx/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml
>   did fail. Reason is : Interceptor class :
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor must have at
>   least one @InterceptorBinding     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.configureInterceptors(BeansDeployer.java:1464)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromXML(BeansDeployer.java:1338)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:189)
>     at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)  at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:913)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Jul 06, 2018 10:45:27 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder
>   startInternal SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war
>   StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myproject]
>   javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: couldn't start owb
>   context   at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:191)
>     at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)  at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:913)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: WebBeans
>   configuration defined in
>   jar:file:/home/xxxxxxx/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml
>   did fail. Reason is : Interceptor class :
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor must have at
>   least one @InterceptorBinding     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:189)
>     ... 15 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: WebBeans
>   configuration defined in
>   jar:file:/home/xxxxxxx/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml
>   did fail. Reason is : Interceptor class :
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor must have at
>   least one @InterceptorBinding     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.configureInterceptors(BeansDeployer.java:1464)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromXML(BeansDeployer.java:1338)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:196)
>     ... 16 more
>
> Jul 06, 2018 10:45:27 PM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle
>   transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myproject]]
>   in state [STARTING_PREP]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:826)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1627)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1307)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Jul 06, 2018 10:45:27 PM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myproject]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myproject]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     ... 6 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException:
>   javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: couldn't start owb
>   context   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1310)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more Caused by:
>   javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: couldn't start owb
>   context   at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:191)
>     at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)  at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:913)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: WebBeans
>   configuration defined in
>   jar:file:/home/xxxxxxx/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml
>   did fail. Reason is : Interceptor class :
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor must have at
>   least one @InterceptorBinding     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:189)
>     ... 15 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: WebBeans
>   configuration defined in
>   jar:file:/home/xxxxxxx/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml
>   did fail. Reason is : Interceptor class :
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor must have at
>   least one @InterceptorBinding     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.configureInterceptors(BeansDeployer.java:1464)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromXML(BeansDeployer.java:1338)
>     at
>   org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:196)
>     ... 16 more
>
> Jul 06, 2018 10:45:27 PM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Jul 06, 2018 10:45:27 PM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide interceptors in your `beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

  <interceptors>
    <class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringCdiInterceptor</class>
    <class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor</class>
  </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you Dirk, this gets me to the next level - now I need a binding:   `Interceptor class : net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringAsynchronousCdiInterceptor must have at least one @InterceptorBinding` -   Isn't it possible to use javamelody without changes to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue [#802](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/802) of javamelody with OpenEJB like in TomEE.
The issue is fixed for the next version (1.76) to be released in a few months.

Meanwhile you may workaround the issue by adding a file WEB-INF/exclusions.list in your webapp with the following content:

```
# inherit from defaults, this is important to keep it
default-list
# ignore javamelody interceptors
javamelody-core-1.73.1.jar
```